# Render Tiptap editor look like a MUI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tiptap

How can I render a [tiptap editor](https://tiptap.dev/installation/react) the same as a [material-ui text field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/)?

I am referring to the outlined or standard variant of the [material-ui text field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/). To have the same look and feel, especially the border of a [material-ui text field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/). Or is there a way to embed the [tiptap editor](https://tiptap.dev/installation/react) inside a [material-ui text field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/)?

Does someone have a solution or an approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I released a package `mui-tiptap` (https://github.com/sjdemartini/mui-tiptap), which styles a Tiptap editor using Material-UI. Its default appearance/variant is set up to resemble the MUI `TextField` "outlined" variant, which has the border you mention.

It's customizable, so if you already have your own controls menu bar, you can use that, or you can take advantage of the components, extensions, etc. that come with `mui-tiptap` to get set up more quickly.

You can try it out yourself at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-tiptap-demo-3zl2l6) or install and use in your project per the GitHub README.

[image: mui-tiptap demo]